# How to calculate value from different function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate several values from an option selected.

```
<label>Processor</label> </br>
        <form action="3.php" method="POST"> 
            <select id="proSelect" name="processor" onchange="proSelectValue()">
                <option value="0">Pilih Processor</option>
                <?php echo $pro_option;?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="proPrice" readonly placeholder="0"></br></br>

        <label>Motherboard</label></br>
            <select id="moboSelect" name="motherboard" onchange="moboSelectValue()">
                <option value="0">Pilih Motherboard</option>
                <?php echo $mobo_option;?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="moboPrice" readonly placeholder="0"></br></br>
```

There the options is show, and if the option selected then the value of the options is shown in the `id="proPrice"` and `id="moboPrice"`. 
And the javascript for the value on the `id="proPrice"` is

```
function proSelectValue() {
        var selObj = document.getElementById("proSelect");
        var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

        document.getElementById("proPrice").value = selValue;
    }

function moboSelectValue() {
        var selObj = document.getElementById("moboSelect");
        var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

        document.getElementById("moboPrice").value = selValue;
    }
```

Now I wanted to calculate all of the value and show in this input

```
<label>Total Harga</label>
    <input type="text" id="totalPrice" readonly>
```

How do i calculate the all of the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another function to calculate the total and call that function inside both the event handler function.

**Demo:**

```js
function proSelectValue() {
  var selObj = document.getElementById("proSelect");
  var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

  document.getElementById("proPrice").value = selValue;
  
  total();
}

function moboSelectValue() {
  var selObj = document.getElementById("moboSelect");
  var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

  document.getElementById("moboPrice").value = selValue;
  total();
}
function total(){
  var total = Number(document.getElementById("proPrice").value) + Number(document.getElementById("moboSelect").value);
  document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = total;
}
```

```html
<label>Processor</label> <br>
<form action="3.php" method="POST"> 
  <select id="proSelect" name="processor" onchange="proSelectValue()">
    <option value="0">Pilih Processor</option>
    <option value="1">Pilih Processor 2</option>
    <option value="2">Pilih Processor 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="proPrice" readonly placeholder="0"><br>     <br>

<label>Motherboard</label><br>
  <select id="moboSelect" name="motherboard" onchange="moboSelectValue()">
    <option value="0">Pilih Motherboard </option>
    <option value="1">Pilih Motherboard 2</option>
    <option value="2">Pilih Motherboard 3</option>
  </select>
    <input type="text" id="moboPrice" readonly placeholder="0">       <br><br>

  <label>Total Harga</label>
  <input type="text" id="totalPrice" readonly />
</form>
```

Comment: what if i want to separate the javascript and the html? it doesnt work if i separate the javascript

Comment: @DeanTristaNato, if the JavaScript file is linked to the HTML file then the code should work without any issues:)